# Euclidean geometry applied to Ptolemy geocentric model

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

I'm looking for a good reference on how Ptolemy used the Euclidean geometry to calculate the planets positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always read Ptolemy himself.  His "*Almagest*", together with the "*On the Revolutions of Heavenly Spheres*" by Copernicus and some extracts from Kepler can be found in "*Great Books of the Western World Vol. 16*".  Bookfinder.com lists used copies going at about $15.00 US.

Richard Fitzpatrick has prepared an excellent analysis entitled "*A Modern Almagest: An updated version of Ptolemy's Almagest*" which can be found at http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/Books/Syntaxis/Syntaxis.html.